# Is DateWithin30Days(Date 1, Date 2) an Apex Method?

Tags: apex, date

I'm working on the #APEX Unit Testing unit on #TrailHead, and I saw what appears to be a very useful Date method, **DateWithin30Days(date1, date2)** This would be very useful for some of my projects, but I can't find it any where in the APEX documentation.

Here is the code sample:

```
public static Date CheckDates(Date date1, Date date2) {
    //if date2 is within the next 30 days of date1, use date2.  Otherwise use the end of the month
    if(DateWithin30Days(date1,date2)) {
        return date2;
    } else {
        return SetEndOfMonthDate(date1);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's probably just a private method inside that particular class. If it was a Salesforce method, it would have a namespace, like System, Date, etc. Where is this code?

Comment: Short answer, no. The lack of prefix to that class tells me that either it's a method on the same class you're on or on a class that your class inherits from. Maybe you can find it within the trailhead you're on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `DateWithin30Days(Date 1, Date 2)` that you have referred here is **not** a standard [`Date` method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm).

It is though still an Apex method but declared right within the class where you see this code. You are most likely looking at [this code from trailhead](https://github.com/developerforce/trailhead-code-samples/blob/master/VerifyDate.cls), which you can always utilize for your purpose.

```
//method to check if date2 is within the next 30 days of date1
private static Boolean DateWithin30Days(Date date1, Date date2) {
    //check for date2 being in the past
        if( date2 < date1) { return false; }

        //check that date2 is within (>=) 30 days of date1
        Date date30Days = date1.addDays(30); //create a date 30 days away from date1
    if( date2 >= date30Days ) { return false; }
    else { return true; }
}
```

Comment: I literally just saw this in the class. I was expecting it to be declared at the top, not the bottom. Looks like the same is for SetMonthEndOfDate.

Comment: It's easy and okay to miss things at times :)

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no.

The lack of prefix to that class tells me that either it's a method on the same class you're on or on a class that your class inherits from. Maybe you can find it within the trailhead you're on?

However, here is a way to do what you need, with a little more flexibility

```
public static Boolean DateWithinXDays(Date startDate, Date endDate, Integer days) {
   return (startDate.daysBetween(endDate) <= days)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. That method helps, I figured I could write my own, but didn't want to waste the time if it was a standard method. It might be in the trailhead, but my hunch is that they did what you have here. Thanks.

Comment: Jayant below pasted the code that exists in the Trailhead. Frankly, I kinda prefer this one...

Answer (score 2):

It's part of the [sample code](https://github.com/developerforce/trailhead-code-samples/blob/master/VerifyDate.cls) for [Get Started With Apex Unit Tests](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro). The link to the sample code is located in the Challenge section of the module.

You might want to complete the more recent and more thorough [Unit Testing on the Lightning Platform](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/unit-testing-on-the-lightning-platform) module in lieu of, or in addition to, this module.